# the sort decriptor is not working in the NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: objective-c, nssortdescriptor, nsfetchedresultscontroller

i am working on a core data app that uses NSFetchedResultsController. i'm sorting the results by string fname. i have added a sort descriptor but the results were unsorted and it throws codedata error while fetching.

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Contact"];
    [request setIncludesPendingChanges:NO];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name.fname.string" ascending:YES];
    [request setSortDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];
    _fetchController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                           managedObjectContext:[BCSCoreDataInterface sharedInstance].mainQueueContext
                                                            sectionNameKeyPath  :@"name.fname.stringGroupByFirstInitial"                                                   cacheName            :nil];

    self.fetchController.delegate = self;

    NSError *error = nil;

    if (![self.fetchController performFetch:&error]) {
        // error handling
    }
```

Comment: Can you post details of the error?

Comment: @DanSpag CoreData: error: (NSFetchedResultsController) The fetched object at index 2 has an out of order section name 'A. Objects must be sorted by section name'

Comment: i think _fetchcontroller itself assigns to property fetchcontroller

Comment: the code didnt work as the fname attribute of name is of transformable type. it didnt have the getter or property string.

Comment: changing the fname from transformable to string type is the solution for this!!

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name.fname.string" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

**EDIT**

For what I can see you are setting your sort descriptor to be "name.fname.string", but the first sort descriptor you pass to the results controller will sort the section, and your sort descriptor doesn't match the sectionNameKeyPath.
So you need to add a first sort descriptor to sort the sections and then the second one to sort the rows in each section. So try this:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sectionSort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey@"name.fname.stringGroupByFirstInitial" ascending:YES];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name.fname.string" ascending:YES];

[request setSortDescriptors: @[sectionSort, sortDescriptor]];
```

Good luck.